# golang read private attribute of a struct in another package

Tags: go

I understand on golang we have public and private fields

```
package main
type User struct {

    DisplayName string 

    title *string 
}
```

Displayname is public so I can read it from another package. title is private I cannot read direclty

what about I add a public method like this

```
package main
type User struct {

    DisplayName string 

    title *string 
}
func (user *User) PublicTitle() string {
  return user.title
}

type EmployeeUser User
```

So I should be able to read title by localUser.PublicTitle() in another package?

```
package utility

var localUser *main.EmployeeUser
 
localUser.PublicTitle()
```

I have tried it seems not working. I am a bit confused.

Thanks for help

Comment: It should work. What is not working?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I have updated a bit my case. Not sure why it is not working. I have a EmployeeUser type. Is that  the reason not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `EmployeeUser` is a new type. When you define a new type based on an existing one, the methods of base type are not promoted to the new type.

To do that, you have to embed:

```
type EmployeeUser struct {
    User
}
```